# The usage of bare infinitive in an article

Tags: verbs

I came across this article. The first sentence is

> One Direction plan on celebrating their 10th anniversary on July 23rd with a trove of new content for their passionate fans.

and the whole article can be seen in this [link](https://www.rollingstone.com/music/music-news/one-direction-anniversary-plans-1027928/)

My question is, Why the verb should've taken a bare infinitive form instead of normal forms like "plans" or "planed"?

Comment: That is not a bare infinitive. It is a finite verb in the sentence.

Comment: Oh,,,, Thank you. Then is One Direction a plural noun?

Comment: still confusing 

Comment: Whether a company/organization/institution should be treated as singular or plural in its grammatical number depends on the dialect, the nature of the entity and the writer. This question is often asked here on this site. In your sentence, One Direction takes plural verbs in grammatical number.